# Delete chef vault items without admin rights

Tags: chef-infra

I would like to delete a Chef Vault item in Hosted Chef but I don't have permission and there is no other administrator of the vault.

```
knife vault delete secrets my-secret

ERROR: ChefVault::Exceptions::SecretDecryption: secrets/my-secret 
is encrypted for you, but your private key failed to decrypt the 
contents.  (if you regenerated your client key, 
have an administrator of the vault run 'knife vault refresh')
```

I was using Hosted chef and I created an item and then later deleted the clientkey which I used to create it - I therefore have no administrator for it. There is no server which has permission to use the item either. Nothing.

Without permission it won't:

- allow me to delete the item
- add the same item over the current one

On the website:

- I can't see any Hosted-Chef menu item to delete vault items.
- [You can't delete the organisation either in hosted chef](https://getchef.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206131846-How-Can-I-Delete-an-Organization-) - which might have been a way of starting it all again.

How can you remove this item?

---

#### Deleting them as if they were a data_bag:

Answer suggested by coderanger:

```
knife vault list
secrets

knife vault show secrets
postfix-auth

# Vault items are just data bag items (two items actually) 
# so just delete them via that.
knife data_bag delete secrets postfix-auth -y
Deleted data_bag_item[postfix-auth]

# The second one is the same name but with _keys 
# appended and holds the item metadata.
knife data_bag delete secrets postfix-auth_keys -y
Deleted data_bag_item[postfix-auth_keys]

# Just to see I am actually doing something I delete it again
knife data_bag delete secrets postfix-auth_keys -y
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: Cannot load data bag secrets item postfix-auth_keys
# Yes the original delete of postfix-auth_keys did something. 
# Lets confirm it ...

# knife vault list now empty!
knife vault list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vault items are just data bag items (two items actually) so just delete them via that. The second one is the same name but with `_keys` appended and holds the item metadata.